# How to bypass SSIS VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, export-to-excel

I've created a SSIS package using the Import/Export utility from SQL Server to export data from a view to an Excel file. I've also scheduled it through a schedule in SQL Server and everything is working perfectly.

The view that I'm exporting data from is actually taking data from multiple views and so on, for about 3 levels in "hierarchy".

I'm encountering an error `VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA` when I modify the column aliases of any of the views that go into the top level view, from which I'm exporting data.

After research I understand that this is why I'm getting the error, but is there any way to "propagate" the metadata of the "new view" so I don't have to recreate the SSIS package everytime I make a change in the structure of the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. A data flow in SSIS is tightly bound to the source. A change to the column name or data type is going to cause the validation step to fail resulting in your error.

To mitigate against it, I would either look at keeping your column aliases the same - views/table valued functions/stored procedures are handy in this regard.

The other approach that I would use is to automate the package creation. Based on your profile, I suspect this would a simple thing to do. Rather than right-click in SSMS to recreate your SSIS package per change, use whatever technology you find appropriate. I've used the base .NET SSIS libraries for package creation but they're painful for me when I'm working with COM (data flow items). I then built packages using the EzAPI which abstracts away some of the COM stuff but it's not 100% feature complete. My current love for alternate package construction is [Biml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Intelligence_Markup_Language).

Download [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex. It's free and provides a lot of useful functionality that didn't make the cut for SSIS/SSRS/SSAS development. Nestled away in there is the ability to transform the Biml XML into SSIS package XML. You can [look through my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181965%20biml) and see some of the ways it works. In your case, it's going to be a very basic OLE DB Source to an Excel Destination. You specify the source view name and any time you make a change to the view, click generate package and you're done. Biml will reach out to your source, identify the metadata and use that to generate the datatypes and names for your destination.

Comment: Hi billinkc, can you send some sample biml code to bypass this error or how to refresh automatically source metadata

Comment: Um... BIML requires recreating the SSIS package every time the spreadsheet is changed. Yes. It automates that process in visual studio. But it cannot be automatically ran from within the SSIS package that has been deployed to SQL Server or elsewhere. BIML, although helpful to some, does not answer the question as presented.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce The answer is in the first sentence - it cannot be done and I explain the why. I propose two approaches to avoiding the root cause. The first is to quit changing your source. The second is to take an approach that can automate the fixing of the problem

Comment: @billinkc it can be done. As OP doesn't mention data flow being a requirement. But had not proved it at the time. My apologies though. BIML was a waste of my time. And I did not get from your answer that BIML would not "discover" schema. Even with advanced scripts that almost did.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that works is to make a Script Task that reads your table schema and adds or alters it, based on the data coming from your file. And you will have to custom parse your file via C#. And connect and write your your database via C#. And to maintain performance equal to SSIS, implement an IDataReader and pass that to SqlBulkCopy. DataTable might implement IDataReader too.

Or to buy a 3rd party utility that connects into SSIS. And deploy that product's assembly to SQL Server.

I will say, it is a huge pain. I have found that saving the .csv to Hadoop / HDFS + SQL Server and Polybase making it automatically queryable without etl is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and in my case it was the source component failed while reading from Azure Blob storage. Took couple of hours to figure out and finally resolve this. Even though the column names were all same w.r.t previous file and successful load this time around the case of few columns' were changed and so is the error "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA". After I got the case of column names corrected the file loaded successfully. Hope this helps.